# Auto-start or any code execution on installation of windows store app?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

My very simple Windows Store App (c#) only shows some data on it's tile. To initialize it, at the moment, the app has to be started by the user which is impractical.

Is there a possibility to auto-start the app or to execute any code on installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there's no way to execute any code without actually starting the app. This means that the user will need to start the app to initialize the tile and its data. You have multiple options for setting up your data then:

- You can create a fixed tile directly from the app.
- You can register the trigger and refresh the tile from there.
- You can setup push notifications for refreshing the tile.

Considering this I suggest you try to make the best out of your app that needs to be run. For example you could show a preview of the tile and add some options for configuring it if that makes sense in you case.

Comment: I also see it that way - there's no possibility to automatically start the app. All right, then I have to live with that. My colleague now had the Idea to initially make a tile with the text "Click me", and there's not much else to do.
Thank you!

Comment: That's a shame. So, what's the point then on registering the background task in the manifest? shouldn't the OS broadcast trigger events to those apps whose manifests indicate interest in the given event/trigger, like in Android?

Comment: @JaimeBotero Yes, OS will trigger registered background tasks, but you can only register background tasks from within your application, i.e. the application will need to be started at least once to register the background tasks. The tasks are not registered at install time.